# Equivalent of return view('path',compact('data1', 'data2', 'data3' )) of laravel in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

How can I get equivalent of

```
return view('path',compact('data1', 'data2', 'data3' ))
```

in ajax success. I have gone through other similar questions in Laravel some of them are suggesting render method which is actually not a redirect.

Previously, I was passing data as:

```
return view('path',compact('data1', 'data2', 'data3' ))
```

But, now I have updated method of file uploading to ajax method, but I got stuck on how to pass other parameters with exactly same structure. So, I don't need to update other code.

I wish to have equivalent code so that I don't need to update any code while using these data passed from here.

### Ajax

`
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(event){

```
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
            url: "{{url('admin/voter/sub/storecsv')}}",
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                $("#csv_uploading").modal('show');
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        $('.uploadProgressBar').attr('aria-valuenow',percentComplete).css('width',percentComplete + '%').text(percentComplete + '%');
                        if (percentComplete === 100) {
                            $("#csv_uploading").modal('hide');
                        }

                    }
                }, false);

                return xhr;
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success:function(data){
                if(data.success === true){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

`

### HTML

```
<form action="{{url('admin/voter/sub/storecsv')}}" class="form-horizontal file-upload" id="file_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input required="" type="file" name="import_file" id="import_file" />
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="upload_csv" disabled="true" type="submit">Import CSV or Excel File</button>
</form>
```

So, if there is any sweet and simple method please let me know.

Comment: So you wish to change code without changing code because other code was changed? I either don't understand you, or what you're asking is just plain impossible.

Comment: @loek what will be your suggestion. If you have any best idea, I would love to follow that way.

Answer (score 0):

in the same function, you need to check if the request was ajax.

```
public function method(){
   if(request()->ajax()){
      return Response([
         'data1' => $data1,
         'data2' => $data2,
         'data3' => $data3,
      ]);
   }
}
```

Don't forget to include `use Response;` This will return a response to the ajax method.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking what after that, this will return to only ajax. Now, how to pass that data to view?

Comment: Show your ajax code and html so that I can build from that.

Comment: Please, have a look to the question. I have updated it with ajax code